# Interpretation of dependent variable when one independent variable is a percentage

Tags: multiple-regression, interpretation, percentage

I have the following regression:

$Revenue = B_0 + B_1*ForecastError + B_2*OilPrice$

Revenue is in dollars, Forecast error is in percentage but written out as decimals  (Example the data is written down as 0.05 and not as 5%) and Oil price is in dollars.

If B1 is - 8000, then I would interpret the independent variable and its impact on the dependent variable by $\frac{B1}{100}$.

"A 1% increase in forecast error will, ceteris paribus and on average, reduce the revenue by 80 dollars".

1. Is this interpretation correct, or do I need to perform a log transformation on the independent variable?
2. Does the fact that the forecasterror variable is expressed as a % influence the interpretation of the other independent variable oil on the dependent variable?